# Why does this Laravel 8 API throw an Internal Server Error?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am working with a Laravel 8 API, that I cloned.

It works on a live server but on my local WAMP server it throws a `500 Internal Server Error`.

The `apache_error.log` shows:

> Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

The content of the `.htaccess` file, placed in the *public* directory (where the virtual host points) is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, DELETE, PATCH, POST, PUT, OPTIONS"

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

##### NOTE:

Other PHP / Laravel applications *do work* on the local environment.

Also, mod_rewrite *is* enabled.

##### What is causing the issue?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved to trigger the problem. Or is this configuration already all the code (which would make Laravel completely unrelated to the problem)?

Comment: "_or defined by a module not included in the server configuration_" Looks like you need to enable `mod_headers` in your Apache

Comment: @RazvanZamfir If you could add the steps to enable the module in WAMP as comment to my answer I'll add those to my answer to make it more complete. I have no idea how it's done in WAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*...or defined by a module not included in the server configuration*" suggests that you need to enable a module first. `Header` is part of [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) in Apache.

Enable that module in your WAMP to make `Header` work.

Go to `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\conf`, open *httpd.conf* find `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so` and uncoment it.

Then restart WAMP.

Comment: I have added the steps, I hope I was clear.